# How to send mail from Oracle DBCS with Office365 account?

Tags: database, oracle, office365, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have

- Oracle DBCS (Identity service account).
- Office365 email account

Now I want to send email from Oracle DBCS. How to do it?

Can you please share any MOS Document or reference materials?

Regards,

Karthick.R

Answer (score 0):

that should help

```
c := utl_smtp.open_connection(l_system.notif_smtp_server,25);

    utl_smtp.helo(c, l_system.notif_smtp_server);
          utl_smtp.mail(c, l_system.notif_sender_address);
          utl_smtp.rcpt(c, l_array_email(i));
          utl_smtp.open_data(c);
          send_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding:','8bit');
          send_header('Content-Type'              , 'text/html; CHARSET=UTF-8');
          send_header('From'                      , '"'||l_system.notif_sender_address||'" '||'<'||l_system.notif_sender_address||'>');
          send_header('To'                        , l_array_email(i));
          send_header('Subject'                   , p_subject  );

          tput
           (p_array_text => get_header);
          tput
           (p_array_text => get_body_header);
          tput
           (p_array_text => p_array_text);
          tput
           (p_array_text => get_footer_beta);
          utl_smtp.close_data(c);
          utl_smtp.quit(c);
```